# Showing price breakdown in Stripe element with payment intent

Tags: android, stripe-payments, tax

I'm trying to use stripe sdk for android to create a payment sheet, and I noticed that there is no option to pass to the payment intent (on the server side) some kind of tax object, or price breakdown. For example - if the price is 12.99 i would like to show that 10.99 is the item price and 2 is the tax.

It is possible on stripe's checkout session API but I couldn't do it on stripe's payments API.
Anyone was able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to pass tax as a separate line item with PaymentIntents API. You'd rather want to rely on the Tax API for custom flows instead: https://stripe.com/docs/tax/custom

Additionally, PaymentSheet doesn't have a built-in UI to show breakdown of the pricing period. You'd need to build the UI yourself, ideally before you present PaymentSheet.